# Creating a minidump in a Python application (Windows)

Tags: python, winapi, stack-trace, crash-dumps

I'm working on a Python application. Sometimes the interpreter crashes when in a third party C++ DLL.

I'm thinking about writing a Python extension that installs a handler for unhandled structured exceptions (Windows) in order to write a minidump to the disk and log the stack trace of every Python thread.

Two questions:

1. Does a Python extension with a similar purpose already exist? According to my own Google search, nothing seems to be publicly available, but maybe I didn't search enough.
2. Is it feasible to implement something like this? (I'm experienced in C++ and Windows programming, but have never implemented a Python extension...)

Comment: It's completely possible to crash the interpreter without leaving a stacktrace or a hook to catch the error. Are you actually getting Python exceptions or things like access violations?

Comment: @delnan: I'm getting access violations - which I want to be able to analyze post-mortem, even when they only occur on user machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [FaultHandler](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler) on PyPI.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will be very useful to me!

Answer (score 1):

I recently wanted to do the same thing and created [minidumper](https://bitbucket.org/briancurtin/minidumper) to do so, and did a small write-up of it [here](http://blog.briancurtin.com/2011/09/29/minidumper-python-crash-dumps-on-windows/).